# Does forcing cast crash the share extension?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, casting, share-extension

I was reviewing "old" code (not that old, but a developer went away and we are documenting and reviewing his code), when, in the context of a iOS Share Extension, I found the following two lines:

```
let content = self.extensionContext!.inputItems[0] as! NSExtensionItem
for attachment in content.attachments as! [NSItemProvider] {
```

**The first line**: I red the docs and found `inputItems` can be empty too, so I suppose that forced cast will crash the app if this thing should happen (I don't know exactly *how*, but maybe it could).

**The second line**: same as above, with the difference that if you have no crash in the first line you probably won't have another here.

Question 1: is it a good idea to check the length of `inputItems` before the loop?

Question 2: I made a little edit to this code and I changed the first line to this:

```
let content = self.extensionContext!.inputItems[0] as? NSExtensionItem
```

After doing so, XCode suggests a correction to the second line I don't like very much (I consider it not readable):

```
for attachment in (content?.attachments as? [NSItemProvider])!
```

is the XCode suggestion the way to go?

Any comment is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to unwrap optionals before accessing the object itself.

You can use `guard` to unwrap the optional chain before proceeding to work with the content.

```
guard let content = self.extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem else { return }
guard let attachments = content.attachments as? [NSItemProvider] else { return }

for attachment in attachments {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Resources:

[Statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html)

[Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html)

Comment: Ok. I don't understand well the second line, that is: content.attachments are guaranteed to be NSItemProvider (they always are)

Comment: From the docs: _(attachment) Contains images, videos, URLs, and so on. This is not meant to be an array of alternate data formats or types, but is instead a collection to include in a social media post, for example. These items are always typed NSItemProvider_

Comment: See the updated answer. This code will safely unwrap all the optionals before accessing the data. If a value is nil, the function returns from execution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to review the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) for Swift optionals

Forced unwrapping will crash the app when encountering nil values which are different from empty arrays.

**Question 1**: No, you don't have to, for-in loops account for the length of the array. Also, the code will loop over `content.attachments` not `inputItems`.

**Question 2**: Your edit of the first line caused `content` to become an optional value, requiring some kind of unwrapping in the second line

If you can be sure the casts will always work the way your developer had it is fine. If you want more safety I would probably do:

```
guard let content = self.extensionContext?.attachments.first as? NSExtensionItem,
      let attachments = content.attachments as? [NSItemProvider] else
{
    // fatalError()
    return
}

for attachment in attachments
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Ok, but if the developer forces an empty array to be of a certain type what happens?

Comment: The cast will still compare array types, the for-in loop will do nothing

Comment: inputType[0] is expected to be of a certain type: if I force inputType[0] (that can be nothing too, since the array can be empty) to be of type NSExtensionItem, won't the app crash?

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying, in that case the app won't crash from the cast, it will crash because of index out of bounds, checking `attachments.first` like @laffen has will account for that, will edit my response as well